Assumptions in a ideal circuit which consists of ideal wires(zero resistance)
Let us say a circuit consists only of a battery and ideal wires. Assuming steady state, if we remove the battery and now complete the circuit with only ideal wires, is it safe to say that the electrons in the circuit will remain in the state of motion forever, as there is no other way by which they can expend their energy.

Is there something contradictory about electrons moving forever? Stars have been, and will be, going around the galaxy practically forever.

Nothing contradictory,it just felt wrong intuitively for some reason.

You're asking extremely good questions, but you need to break out of the electronics model that you have in your head. It can't help you here:

Let us say a circuit consists only of a battery and ideal wires.

No. If that was the case, there would be an infinite amount of current flowing.
That isn't possible, and even under idealized assumptions, it doesn't allow you to make any conclusion on the behaviour.
You simply violate the boundaries in which the model "schematic" works.
So, you mustn't start any physical thought that way.
You can of course say you have a finite current circling in a superconductive ring. And yes, this current would circle forever, as long as nothing interferes with the magnetic field it produces.
Now, I assume you are studying electrical engineering. If that's the case, you'll hopefully soon have a lecture on electromagnetic fields and waves, and on solid-state electronics and semiconductors. The following "previews" a bit of that, so you can have something to look forward to!

is it safe to say that the electrons

Really, when thinking of currents, don't think in electrons. If you dig into this on a physical side, namely, reading up on Maxwell's equations and combining that with the principle of impulse conservation, you'll notice that this doesn't work as nicely when you think of current as quantum thing, made out of individual electrons. (The electron model of current quickly breaks down once you need it to explain electromagnetism, which is a wave phenomenon, and things like energy transport along superconductors. In fact, it's not even fit to explain energy transport along any conductor. It's very useful to put up a simplified model about how semiconductors work, but as soon as you go any deeper into that, you'll notice that "identifiable" electrons travelling through solid material just aren't a thing. Well, in some cases we try very hard to describe things as such, which leads to us assigning effective mass to electrons, higher than their mass at rest. But that is "retrofitting" a complicated quantum model on a physical observation.)
In fact, you probably heard of the Heisenberg principle, namely that you can't know the location of something precisely when you know the impulse of that thing precisely. Here, your electrons have extremely well-known impulse, defined by the current, which defines the energy of the magnetic field that they all share, so their location becomes extremely "blurred": there's just a uniform "soup" of "there might be electrons of this specific impulse here with a certain probability" along your ring. No individual electron can be made out, and that probability soup doesn't observably "rotate" – it's constant along the ring.

It depends on your exact definition of "ideal wire". Yes, a superconducting loop can store energy indefinitely, but only because of its inductance — the energy is stored in its magnetic field.

There is no such thing as a completely ideal circuit- even a superconducting circuit will have some inductance. The speed of light is real and circuits have finite size. If energy is sloshing back and forth between a capacitor and an inductor in a tank circuit some of it will be lost to RF or other losses even if there is no resistance. Insulators are not perfect, and so on.
It is often useful to ignore real factors to get easy useful results and insights, but if you ignore too many you get useless results. For example, an ideal voltage source shorted with an ideal wire with no resistance or inductance. What is the current at any point in time- you can’t make any sensible prediction with such a simplistic model. If you add in circuit inductance, voltage source resistance, or circuit resistance you’ll avoid the paradox but the results still may not be useful if they don’t reflect reality.
A real superconducting coil is charged by applying a voltage to the zero resistance coil. The current increases linearly with time due to the inductance. After the current has increased sufficiently the circuit is closed with a special device (voltage source current-limits) and a persistent current flows. We can get a very accurate prediction while still ignoring a whole slew of factors, but not too many.
In some situations you must use a field solver (or solve it analytically in the rare simple situations where that is possible) to get useful results, but it's okay ignore electrons and ignore relativistic effects. In some situations quantum effects are important or dominant. Two ideal resistors connected in parallel in the simplest model do not interact. But if they are at different temperatures they do interact. The real universe is so complex it's nice that we can ignore most of the complexity in many situations to get useful results.

A battery, especially an ideal one, won’t work since it has zero resistance. With zero resistance wires you know what happens :)
What will work nicely is a current source. If you have a current source driving a superconducting wire, and then a superconducting shunt is closed across the current source, the current will indeed flow in the wire indefinitely as long as it is superconducting and as long as the current density and magnetic flux don’t cause local loss of super-conductivity. That’s usually bad news as quite a bit of energy is stored in the magnetic field when the current is high.

what do you mean by a current source?, is it hypothetical or is it real?
